# Is preset dictionary is only useful for first 32 K bytes of data ?

Tags: linux, algorithm, dictionary, compression, zlib

I Just wanted to use preset dictionary with my compressor and de-compressor. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295036/is-there-a-way-to-store-gzips-dictionary-from-a-file) that preset dictionary is only helpful for first 32K bytes of data and after that the most recent 32K data is used as dictionary. Is it true? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the preset dictionary is used as virtual input to the decompressor that was processed before the actual compressed input, so it can use compressed codes to replicate parts of it.

The deflate algorithm of zlib uses a window of up to 32 KB size to refer to bytes decompressed before - parts of this window and byte literals are all it can use for decompression. The preset dictionary just initialises this window, but data there will be "shifted out" by the real decompressed data, so only the first 32K bytes of data can use a decreasing part of the preset dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This means preset dictionary can not help us through out the compression.

Comment: One more clarification: If i use preset dictionary with dictionary string "aaaaaaa". I have my data which contains this string at 16K offset, 34K offset and 66K offset respectively. According to your answer, it uses preset dictionary for string which is at 16K offset. But what about 34K offset, since it is 34K byte long from preset dictionary and it can not refer that, but it is 18K long from the first reference of the string and it can refer that. So is it uses the first reference or it creates new one in this case.

Comment: @Chinna: Yes, indeed, in such cases where strings from the preset dictionary will appear later in the decompressed data, they "reappear" in the window and can be referenced later. Anyway, this second reference can also be made without a preset dictionary, so the preset dictionary only helps for the first appearance of the string.

Comment: "reappear" means, 1st instance refer to the dictionary, 2nd instance refers to the 1st instance. So this means 2nd instance indirectly refers to the dictionary right ? If there is no dictionary, 1st instance it self replaced at 2nd instance. If there is dictionary, 2nd instance replace with dictionary right? Please provide me any document which explains about preset dictionary.